# Populating jQuery Mobile ListView with local JSON data

Tags: json, listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to populate a JQM ListView with a local JSON information. However, no list items are created. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

**JSON File Structure:**

```
[
{
"name" : "test"
"calories" : "1000"
"fat" : "100"
"protein" : "100"
"carbohydrates" : "800"
},
{
"name" : "test2"
"calories" : "10000"
"fat" : "343"
"protein" : "3434"
"carbohydrates" : "4343"
}
]
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" data-title="Search" id="searchPage">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="searchFood">
      </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

*(Updated)*

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#searchPage", function(){
  $.getJSON("../JS/food.json", function(data){
        var output = '';
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
         output += '<li><a href="#">' +data.name+ '</a></li>';
        });
        $('#searchFood').html(output).listview("refresh");
  });
});
```

Comment: `$('#searchFood').html(output).listview("refresh");`

Comment: Thanks Omar - but still no list items appearing with those changes:/ I have updated the JS on the post to reflect your suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the return *JSON* array is wrong, values (properties) should be separated by commas.

```
var data = [{
    "name": "test",
        "calories": "1000",
        "fat": "100",
        "protein": "100",
        "carbohydrates": "800",
}, {
    "name": "test2",
        "calories": "10000",
        "fat": "343",
        "protein": "3434",
        "carbohydrates": "4343",
}];
```

Second mistake, you should read `value` object returned by `$.each()` function not `data` array.

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
  output += '<li><a href="#">' + value.name + '</a></li>';
});
```

jQueryMobile only enhances the page once when it is loaded. When new data is added dynamically to the page, jQueryMobile must be made aware of the data  for the data to be enhanced.

After extracting data from *JSON* array, append them then *refresh* listview to restyle newly added elements.

```
$('#searchFood').html(output).listview("refresh");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/V8me6/)**