# Jquery mobile : Listview doesn't display correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

am using Jquery mobile 1.4.1. I trying to display a jquery mobile list view but it doesn't display correctly when insert the code using Jquery. The problem is that the jquery doesn't insert the css classes. Here is my code and a screen shot:
[image: screen shot]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web service</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.1.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.getJSON("http://localhost/WebService/web-service.php?format=json", function(result) {
                    var html = "";
                    $.each(result.posts, function(i, field) {
                        html = html.concat("<li><a href='#'>" + field.post.fullname + "</a></li>");
                    });
                    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = html;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Start of first page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="foo">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Foo</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>
                <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p>
                <ul data-role="listview" id="list"></ul>

            </div>
            <!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->
        </div><!-- /page -->

        <!-- Start of second page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="bar">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Bar</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing clicked.</p>
                <p><a href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>
            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->
        </div><!-- /page -->
    </body>

</html>
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populating jQuery Mobile ListView with local JSON data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881830/populating-jquery-mobile-listview-with-local-json-data)

Comment: Refresh your list view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to show as listview?? are they these three items 
1.bar
2.taieb baccouch 
3.zahra daqrir
 than the following code can help you..

```
<div>
<ul data-role="listview" class="jqm-list">
<li><a><span>bar</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>taieb baccouch </span></a></li>
<li><a><span>zahra daqrir</span></li>
</ul></div>
```